# Join Windows and macOS with the same name to Active Directory

Tags: windows, macos, active-directory

I have a lot of iMacs dual-booting macOS and Windows. Up until recently I had them in Active Directory (AD) and Open Directory (OD), the equivalent of AD by Apple. They have the same (host)name, regardless if booted into Windows or macOS.

Now I wanna join the macOS installations to AD too, but if possible I would like to keep the same name (instead of having to rename either).

Is it possible to have both macOS and Windows in the AD, while keeping the same name on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.  You cannot have two computer objects of the same name in Active Directory.  I know this form long time experience with AD.  Please also see the two links below having marked answers on this very subject.

[Will Active Directory Allow You to Add Two Computers of the Same Name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57385/will-active-directory-allow-you-to-add-two-computers-of-the-same-name)

[Two computers same name on same domain](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/205867-two-computers-same-name-on-same-domain)

As info for next time, this type of server question belongs on ServerFault.  Since there's no code here.

Comment: I was hoping for some differences in macOS and WIN, like AD just needing the WINS name or something. But apparently that is not happening. Thanks for the answer and the advice :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Keep in mind, even in WINS, which is a very old, deprecated Microsoft-oriented name resolution technology, you can't have duplicate names.  It doesn't matter what the OS is.  Never tried it myself, but I doubt MACs would have been able to use WINS, even back in the day.

Comment: From reading around I got the impression that maybe, maybe one can have a mac with the HostName "edu123" and the WINS name "edu123-mac". The idea was to then join it to the AD with "edu123-mac" and have the HostName still on "edu123".

Comment: AD only uses hostnames anymore, because it's based on DNS, not WINS. The need for WINS went away with the Advent of Active Directory in 2000. Outside of anything but a specially created lab environment, you likely wouldn't find any support for this idea inside a major production environment.  Unless you were just having fun testing different ideas and such.